# How to know if a Port is available for my application I am going to Install

Tags: ports

I have a very doubt , plz correct me ..

I have a windows server and I need to install a application/product on it . This application/product uses certain ports, and I need to enter those ports while configuring this application.
So I need to know if say 19800 port is available or not.

what I did to know if 19800 is available or not:
1)netstat -na -- this gave me list of ports with status listening/established/Time_wait ..
I didnt find 19800 port in outout of netstat -na..
So does that mean 19800 port is not there and I need to ask window administrator team to open this port?

2)I think netstat -na gives the port which are in use or accepting some connections ..

It actually doesn't give you list of all the ports that the server have , because server generally have more than 60000 ports , and the output from netstat -na gives somewhere 100 entries..

3)what I dream is to know what all ports are there on this server , and if I find my port name I can assign that port to my application.

Thanks
rick

Comment: C:\Users\usertest>telnet localhost 19800
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 19800: Connect failed
what does it mean ?  is port open/blocked/closed or needs to be open by windows admin team??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check, the availability of a PORT, you may use different approaches the simplest one in this case could be depending on your programming language you may do the following:

```
port_available = TRUE
try:
    open(HOST,PORT)
exception PORT_NOT_AVAILABLE:
    port_available = FALSE
```

Using the output from netstat and parsing it using text editor could be a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks ..but this is too complex for me to understand.

Comment: @rickepm kindly tell me what SOCKET APIs you are using, I will help you write code for that.

Comment: Socket APIs?? I don't know this .. I am just on windows server 2008.....
If doing telnet I get this ..
C:\Users\usertest>telnet localhost 19800 Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 19800: Connect failed what does it mean ? 
is port open/blocked/closed or needs to be open by windows admin team??

Comment: It means that no server program is listening on that port.

Comment: In simple worlds that port is free for your application to use.

Comment: Thanks akm . but if its free it should have not given connect failed...
what message i would have got from telnet if the ports are blocked.

Comment: Thanks akm .. if port is available for use , then why its howing connect failed .. 
what message I would have got if the ports are actually cloed/blocked/not there?

Comment: Either your application is using some other port, otherwise it may be running, and if you are trying it to telnet from a different machine it is possible that windows `Firewall` is blocking that port.

Comment: thanks akm .. my concern is very simple , and all what i have seen in forums are confusing . again I am explaining my issue ..
I have to install a application that uses 19800 port .. now what i am trying to do is to find if this port is there / available / etc.. 
I don't want to start the application installation and know that that this port is blocked ..
so what can i do before hand to know if port 19800 is there .

Comment: akm sir .. plz reply?